# Flutter getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() returns a wrong path

Tags: flutter, dart

So, this worked before. It returned a path, of which I only rememdber it having two long numbers separated by a '/', while now it returns "/data/user/0/com.x.y/app_flutter". If copy pasting it into my Finder it shows me the "Macintosh HD" directory, while before I was in the proper app dir. Anyone had this before? It doesn't work on ios or android emulator. Anyone had this before?